# Sequential selection among multiple NSTextViews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, nslayoutmanager, nstextcontainer

I have a bunch of `NSTextView`s that I would like to share a single selection. I basically want this to behave like selecting text on a web page, where there are multiple text views but you can drag to sequentially select text among them.

I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/MultipleViews.html) document which states that it is possible to have multiple `NSTextContainer` objects sharing a single `NSLayoutManager` and thus share the selection. This is halfway to what I want, except for the fact that one `NSLayoutManager` can only have a single `NSTextStorage` object. I want each text view to have its own `NSTextStorage` so that each text view can have its own text, but I still want to be able to select text in multiple text views with one drag. Is this possible?

Comment: did you have any luck finding a solution for this?

Comment: I wrote a solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no *easy* way to solve this problem (as I tried to find by asking this question). It involves all the mouse event handling and text selection calculations you'd expect, so I wrote the code and have open sourced it as [`INDSequentialTextSelectionManager`](https://github.com/indragiek/INDSequentialTextSelectionManager).

Answer (score 0):

To make this separate text containers work, you would calculate the drawn size of each part of the string and limit the NSTextView to that size:

```
    NSLayoutManager * layout = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    NSString * storedString = @"A\nquick\nBrown\nFox";
    NSTextStorage * storage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:storedString];
    [storage addLayoutManager:layout];

    //I assume you have a parent view to add the text views
    NSView * view;

    //Assuming you want to split up into separate view by line break
    NSArray * paragraphs = [storedString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    for (NSString * paragraph in paragraphs)
    {
        NSSize paragraphSize = [paragraph sizeWithAttributes:@{}];
        //Create a text container only big enough for the string to be displayed by the text view
        NSTextContainer * paragraphContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithContainerSize:paragraphSize];
        [layout addTextContainer:paragraphContainer];

        //Use autolayout or calculate size/placement as you go along
        NSRect lazyRectWithoutSizeOrPlacement = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        NSTextView * textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:lazyRectWithoutSizeOrPlacement
                                                    textContainer:paragraphContainer];
        [view addSubview:textView];
    }
```

You can add a delegate to the NSLayoutManager to watch your text container usage:

```
- (void)layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)aLayoutManager
didCompleteLayoutForTextContainer:(NSTextContainer *)aTextContainer
                    atEnd:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (aTextContainer == nil)
    {
        //All text was unable to be displayed in existing containers. A new NSTextContainer is needed.
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies if the original post wasn't clear. I'm not looking to sync the same selection range across multiple text views, but to sequentially select text _between_ text views. I'm looking for something like this: http://d.pr/i/kmnB. In that case it's using a WebView and gets this functionality without any extra work, but I'm looking to replicate the same effect with just text views.

Comment: Ahh.. yes I see what you mean. Editing answer.

Comment: Thanks for the amendments. I actually already have multiple text views working and displaying my text. My problem is specifically **selection**. How do I intercept a mouse drag on _one_ of the text views and have the selection rectangle spread to the selection ranges of text views above/below it when the mouse is dragged over them?